# Square sum of two complex roots of $x^4-2x^3-3x-2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two complex roots of
$$x^4-2x^3-3x-2=0$$
What is the value of $\alpha^2+\beta^2$?

(a) $-1\quad$
(b) $-2\quad$
(c) $-3\quad$
(d) $-4\quad$
(e) $-5\quad$

---

This looked like an easy question but I couldn't solve it. I tried to split the quartic polynomial into two quadratic polynomials but that was not successful either. It's surprising that the answer can be an integer. There must be some clever way to get the answer.

Comment: I guess a typo in the equation.

Comment: yes because wolframalpha provides some big numbers

Comment: not possible because if $\alpha $ and $\beta$ are complex , then $\bar{\alpha}$ and $\bar{\beta}$ are also the roots and the product of the roots is $|\alpha|^2|\beta|^2=-2$ which is not possible.

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma What if $\beta=\overline\alpha$?

Comment: ya you are right, it should have two real and two complex conjugates

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial one,
Let the roots be a,b,c,d; where c and d are real, and a,b are complex conjugates.

let $a=p+iq$,
$b=p-iq$.

We are required to find $$2(p^2-q^2)$$
Notice that $$a+b+c+d=2$$,
$$\implies c+d=2-2p$$
and,
$$abcd=-2$$,
$$\implies c.d=\frac{-2}{p^2+q^2}$$
and $$ab+bc+cd+ac+ad+bd=0$$
If I put the things that I previously derived, I get

$$p^2+q^2+4p(1-p)=\frac{2}{p^2+q^2}$$
By a similar way,
$$abc+abd+bcd+acd=3$$
If I again put the things in terms of p and q, I get:

$$2(1-p).(p^2+q^2)-\frac{4p}{p^2+q^2}=3$$

Now for these equations, Wolfram generates horrible expressions, but gives only 2 real values of p and q, as p and q are real,

$$\implies p=-0.01754 ,q=+_-1.20418$$
giving $$2(p^2-q^2)=-3$$ (approx)

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried it but didn't pursue beyond it. However, this time I tried to solve it as you sounded promising, but I ended up with having to solve a sextic equation, so I gave up again. :-). Thanks anyway (+1).

Comment: Is the answer correct?

Comment: I don't know what the answer is, but I guess -3 is probably the answer!

Comment: There has to be a better way to do this problem..